# Subfig package caption figure problem

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am trying to fix subfigures. I use `subfig` package, but when I try to continue the figure to the next page, the second subfig shows me a wrong figure caption

```
\begin{figure} [!htb]
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0.1pt}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{img1}\label{fig2a}}\\[-1ex]
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{img2}\label{fig2b}}\\[-1ex]
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{img3}\label{fig2c}}\\[-1ex]
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{img4}\label{fig2d}}\\[-1ex]
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{img5}\label{fig2e}}\\[-1ex]
    \caption{Continua}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \ContinuedFloat*
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0.1pt}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{img6}\label{fig2f}}\\[-1ex]
    \caption{Second page}
\end{figure}
```

The first part shows figure 2 but the second part shows figure 1, as I show  in the picture.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem. What happens is that there is an incopatibility between `hyperref` package and `subfig` one. So, the only thing that I had to do is to use `subcaption` package which does the same thing and it worked perfectly.